# Jinja2 Template - CSS not working

Tags: python, css, pandas, jinja2

I have a Python Project that has the following file structure

```
 days_on_hand.py
 templates\
    doh_managers.html
 static\
    style.css
```

Here is my html template code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "/static/style.css">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Days Inventory on Hand -- Warehouse</h2>
     {{ managers_days }}
</body>
</html>
```

I have also used the following `href`

```
    <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= url_for('static', filename='style.css')>
```

I am not seeing any of the css formatting in my output, which is generated using the below:

```
template_vars = {"title": "Days Inventory on Hand -- Warehouse",
                             "managers_days": df.to_html(index=False)}
html_out = template.render(template_vars)
html_file.write(html_out)
```

I am seeing the double border on the table, and my css is as follows and should collapse the border, also the H2 text is not coming out centered.:

```
h2{
    text-align: center;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: Please provide what you are seeing and what you are expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `style.css` file is in the `static` folder of your project, then to make the resource available via [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) WSGI, you'll have to use [`url_for('static', filename='style.css')`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#static-files) in your `href` for the stylesheet.

Comment: I started with that and am still not getting expected results